# Json - Additional column value added to Flatten Key and Values in Hive

Tags: sql, arrays, json, hive, hiveql

In a table having 2 columns and 2 Records :

Record 1 : Column 1 -  my_col value as: `{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"]}` and Column 2 - ID as `A123`

Record 2 : Column 1 -  my_col value as: `{"XXX": ["123","456"],"YYY": ["246","135"], "ZZZ":["333","444"]}` and Column 2 - ID as `B222`

Note: Column2 is not static , every record have different value.

Expectation :

| Key | Value | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 123 | A123 |
| XXX | 456 | A123 |
| YYY | 246 | A123 |
| YYY | 135 | A123 |
| ZZZ | 333 | B222 |
| ZZZ | 444 | B222 |

Query used :

```
SELECT
    t.key,
    kv.kval as value,
    ID
FROM (
    SELECT
         explode(map(
             'XXX',
             split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.XXX'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),','),
             'YYY',
             split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.YYY'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),',')
         )) 
    FROM
        input_df
) t LATERAL VIEW explode(t.value) kv as kval
```

As you recommended flattening is good. Facing issue In retrieve ID value from the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table contains some other columns and you need to select them along with values from explode, then use one more lateral view in the subquery. See comments in the code:

```
SELECT
    t.key,
    kv.kval as value,
    t.ID
FROM (
SELECT 
 e.key, e.value, --columns from lateral view
 t.id  --column from table  
FROM
    input_df t --add alias
    --move explode to lateral view in the FROM
    lateral view explode(map(
         'XXX',
         split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.XXX'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),','),
         'YYY',
         split(regexp_replace(get_json_object(my_col,'$.YYY'),'"|\\[|\\]',''),',')
     )) e as key, value --add alias and col names 
) t LATERAL VIEW explode(t.value) kv as kval
```

Comment: It Works . Thank for your effort

Comment: I got a new request on top of this example. In the above scenario we know the Key XXX and YYY so we specify that in the HQL.                                                                                       
 In my current scenario I don't know the Keys. Query need to identify the KEY and flatten it.

Comment: Can you please help on this.

Comment: Sure.. Let me know how to accept / upvote? Any link there?